# Gatsby Context API doesn't render its value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, react-context

Trying to render state from Context API, but in console it shows as `undefined` and doesn't render anything.

here is Context file

```
import React, { useReducer, createContext } from "react"

export const GlobalStateContext = createContext()
export const GlobalDispatchContext = createContext()

const initialState = {
  isLoggedIn: "logged out",
}

function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "TOGGLE_LOGIN":
      {
        return {
          ...state,
          isLoggedIn: state.isLoggedIn === false ? true : false,
        }
      }
      break

    default:
      throw new Error("bad action")
  }
}

const GlobalContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState)
  return (
    <GlobalStateContext.Provider value={state}>
      {children}
    </GlobalStateContext.Provider>
  )
}

export default GlobalContextProvider
```

and here is where value should be rendered

```
import React, { useContext } from "react"
import {
  GlobalStateContext,
  GlobalDispatchContext,
} from "../context/GlobalContextProvider"

const Login = () => {
  const state = useContext(GlobalStateContext)
  console.log(state)
  return (
    <>
      <GlobalStateContext.Consumer>
        {value => <p>{value}</p>}
      </GlobalStateContext.Consumer>
    </>
  )
}

export default Login
```

I tried before the same thing with class component but it didn't solve the problem. When I console log context it looks like object with undefined values.

Any ideas?

Comment: just to make sure - are you rendering your Login component as a child of GlobalContextProvider somewhere in your app?

Comment: no, Login component is one of page in gatsby, does it mean that I should import context to ```gatsby-ssr.js```?

Comment: not necessarily - i'll explain in an answer

Answer (score 2):

## The Context API In General

From the comments, it seems the potential problem is that you're not rendering `<Login />` as a child of `<GlobalContextProvider />`. When you're using a context consumer, either as a hook or as a function, there needs to be a matching provider somewhere in the component tree as its parent.

For example, these would not work:

```
<div>
    <h1>Please log in!</h1>
    <Login />
</div>
```

```
<React.Fragment>
    <GlobalContextProvider />
    <Login />
</React.Fragment>
```

because in both of those, the Login component is either a sibling of the context provider, or the provider is missing entirely.

This, however, would work:

```
<React.Fragment>
    <GlobalContextProvider>
        <Login />
    </GlobalContextProvider>
</React.Fragment>
```

because the Login component is a child of the GlobalContextProvider.

## Related To Gatsby

This concept is true regardless of what library or framework you're using to make your app. In Gatsby specifically there's a little bit of work you have to do to get this to work at a page level, but it's possible.

Let's say you have a Layout.jsx file defined, and the following page:

```
const Index = () => (
    <Layout>
        <h1>{something that uses context}</h1>
    </Layout>
)
```

You have 2 options:

1. The easier option is to extract that `h1` into its own component file. Then you can put the `GlobalContextProvider` in the `Layout` and put the context consumer in the new component. This would work because the h1 is being rendered as a child of the layout.
2. Is to do some shuffling.

You might be inclined to put the Provider in the layout and try to consume it in the page. You might think this would work because the h1 is still being rendered as a child of the Layout, right? That is correct, but the context is not being consumed by the h1. The context is being *rendered* by the h1 and *consumed* by Index, which is the parent of `<Layout>`. Using it at a page level is possible, but what you would have to do is make another component (`IndexContent` or something similar), consume your context in *there*, and render *that* as a child of layout. So as an example (with imports left out for brevity):

```
const Layout = ({children}) => (
    <GlobalContextProvider>
        {children}
    </GlobalContextProvider>
);

const IndexContent = () => {
    const {text} = useContext(GlobalStateContext);
    return <h1>{text}</h1>;
}

const Index = () => (
    <Layout>
        <IndexContent />
    </Layout>
);
```

Comment: is it in general correct solution if I want to make global state for logged users? So, if user logs in in ```Login``` component, whole app has information that user is logged in.

Comment: yes, in general, that makes sense. and if the state in a context provider changes, only components that consume it will rerender, so making your state global has no impact on performance

Comment: and how to destructure context consumer to get state?

Comment: that's entirely dependent on how you state is structured. if you're having trouble, usually MDN is a good resource: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment